# sql save month boolean fields as integer for bitwise manipulation

Tags: sql-server, binary, bit-manipulation

Probably overthinking this. Issue is I've inherited a database where a member can have two (or more) addresses as part of membership (think seasonal) record (addresses are in separate records), and database actions depend on which address the member is currently located at.

Currently, each month (Jan, Feb, etc.) is a bit field. So in order to query where a member is this month (or span of months) you have to either select for the field name that matches current month (or month span for period), meaning you have to query by variable field name... or scan through the 12 fields - clumsy. Seems to me it should either be an integer field that is queried by bitwise xor operation (one for which months are flagged and one for query period), or by "adding" the field values into a string of bits converted to integer number then using bitwise comparison.

Second option would be ok (wouldn't change the table structure) but would rather use one integer field to represent a binary version of the 12 months then work with that.

In either case, been way too many years since I did much bitwise work, much less figure out how to convert into binary representation. I expect there is already a published answer somewhere, but can't find it. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are open to using an integer field, add a column to your table to hold the month numeric values.

```
alter table myTable
add column MonthNum int

alter table myTable
add constraint CK_Month_Range CHECK (MonthNum > 0 and MonthNum < 13)
```

There wouldn't be any benefit of storing a bit representation of the month number in an integer field since the same amount of space will be taken up (4 bytes). Many system table use bitwise values but in this case, I don't see how it would improve anything.

In order to check if they are there, I would probably do one of two things.

- Use a `bit` value column for IsCurrent
- Use a form of row versioning where the last updated datetime would be the current record

Here is a *bitwise* type of check if your application will send in an integer for the parameter

```
declare @table table (id int identity(1,1), jan bit, feb bit, mar bit, apr bit, may bit, jun bit, jul bit, aug bit, sep bit, oct bit, nov bit, [dec] bit)

insert into @table
values
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0), --aug
(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), --mar
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), --dec
(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)   --jan


declare @month int = 3

select *, bitwise = concat(jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,[dec])
from @table
where charindex('1',concat(jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,[dec])) = @month
```

If they are passing in strings, like 'January', then you'd just join to a lookup table.

Comment: The current structure works fine for some things. The issue gets into needing to find those records that meet the criteria of being true in one or more months (usually one) for reporting. Yes, I can hand code a query that creates a temp table for a specific month, BUT I would like to be able to query for that month field that matches the month being worked - i.e., if it's November, I need to see which member address record is in the month of November as a passed variable to the query, NOT by passing a hard coded month name value. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: What values are in the month column? Can you provide sample data?

Comment: there are 12 month fields (columns), each named for the month (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.). The field is a bit field, values are 0 and 1 - boolean.

Comment: Oh your data is pivoted and unnormalized then. You should fix that

Comment: Well, not really, since the Month fields are not used EXCEPT for a couple of reports monthly. Creating a record for each month is a bit drastic for an address record! 
What I would prefer is using an integer for bitwise manipulation for - i.e, 12 binary places, one for each month, 0 for no, 1 for yes, with the address records having one field for that integer. Then do an xor of the report date (converted to integer) to get a result that tells the report to use that address record for the reporting date. Alternate would be to concatenate the 12 month bits into a number for the comparison.

Comment: the months would be a look up table, not a record for each. However, it could be a single column of month, with values 1-12 like i stated before. Not drastic at all :) I'll add a bitwise in a second

Comment: Again, the issue is that a specific address record could be valid for all 12 months, a set of 6 months, or random months. This has to do with people who have multiple residences that they move to at different times of year, which affects the local chapter that provides services while they are in the area. So, you could have a record that is active January thru May, and a second one that is active June thru December. Currently the appropriate month fields are set true for the active months. Issue arises when doing reporting on where a member is living at the time of the report.

Comment: I can’t guess at your data anymore unfortunately. Without a monomial, complete, verifiable example I’ve exhausted all attempts.